# Black window after returning main view(table view) by tabbar button in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In Root view, I used Tabbar controller and there are 4 tabs.
At first tab View(index = 0), user can search books on open Book API services. It works well, but here is a problem.
1. Users search a book on first tab view (index = 0,tableview)
2. The results come out
3. Users tab other tab button and move other views.
4. Users tab a first button(index=0,table view) for backing to search other books.
5. The Black screen shows up in first tab view, but the user can move to other views by tapping other tabs, there are no black screens. There is a black screen only in the first view(index=0)

What's the problem with my app? 
I coded my app with swift.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SearchHome: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate{

  // MARK: - Properties
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
   // var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "search", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

let apiKey : String = "cbccaa3f----d980b0c"

var searchString : String = ""

var list = Array<BookAPIresult>()

  // MARK: - View Setup
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.searchController.searchBar.text! = ""

    // Setup the Search Controller
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()     
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar


    // Setup the Scope Bar
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["title", "hashtag"]
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "book search"

    // Setup Animation for NavigationBar
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears = false
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
    navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenVerticallyCompact = true

    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SearchHome.handleRefresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    // declare hide keyboard tap
    let hideTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SearchHome.hideKeyboardTap(_:)))
    hideTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(hideTap)

    // declare hide keyboard swipe
    let hideSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SearchHome.hideKeyboardSwipe(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(hideSwipe)

}


    // MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {

    //      filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){

    self.searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text!

    self.list.removeAll()

    self.callBookAPI()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.list.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let row = self.list[indexPath.row]

    NSLog("title:\(row.title),row:\(indexPath.row), author:\(row.author)")


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListCell") as! BookAPIResultCell


    cell.title?.text = row.title
    cell.author?.text = row.author


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ cell.thumb.image = self.getThumbnailImage(indexPath.row)})


    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("%d",indexPath.row)
}



override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.view.endEditing(false)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func callBookAPI(){

    let encodedSearchString = searchString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let apiURI = NSURL(string: "https://apis.daum.net/search/book?apikey=\(self.apiKey)&q=\(encodedSearchString!)&searchType=title&output=json")

    let apidata : NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: apiURI!)


    NSLog("API Result = %@", NSString(data: apidata!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)


    do {

        let data = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(apidata!, options:[]) as! NSDictionary

        let channel = data["channel"] as! NSDictionary
      //  NSLog("\(data)")
        let result = channel["item"] as! NSArray

        var book : BookAPIresult

        for row in result {

            book = BookAPIresult()

            let title = row["title"] as? String


            let decodedTitle = title?.stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


            let titleFromHTML = decodedTitle!.html2String

            let titleRemoveB = titleFromHTML
            let titleRemoveBEnd = titleRemoveB.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</b>", withString: "")
            book.title = titleRemoveBEnd

            if let authorEx = row["author"] as? String{
                book.author = authorEx
            }else{
                book.author = ""
            }

            book.thumbnail = row["cover_s_url"] as? String

            //NSLog("\(book.thumbnail)")
            let description = row["description"] as? String

            let decodedDescription = description?.stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            book.description = decodedDescription!

            self.list.append(book)
        }

        } catch {

            NSLog("parse error")

        }
}



func getThumbnailImage(index : Int) -> UIImage {


    let book = self.list[index]



    if let savedImage = book.thumbnailImage {
        return savedImage
    } else {


        if book.thumbnail == "" {

            book.thumbnailImage = UIImage(named:
                "Book Shelf-48.png")
        }else{

            let url = NSURL(string: book.thumbnail!)



            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

            book.thumbnailImage = UIImage(data:imageData!)
        }






        return book.thumbnailImage!
    }
}

func handleRefresh(refreshControl:UIRefreshControl){

    self.searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text!

    self.list.removeAll()

    self.callBookAPI()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

// hide keyboard if tapped
func hideKeyboardTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

// hide keyboard if swipe
func hideKeyboardSwipe(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return false
}

}



extension String {

var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    guard
        let data = dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        else { return nil }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return  nil
    }
}
var html2String: String {
    return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
}
}
extension SearchHome: UISearchResultsUpdating {
// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
 //   filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
}
}
```

Comment: Have you linked the datasource/delegate etc in IB?

Comment: @AMAN77 link datasource?

Comment: In your storyboard or Xib file you need to link your tableview. Is this your first time working with a tableview?

Comment: @AMAN77 No, I did before, and It worked well.

Comment: Maybe try refreshing the tableview with a viewDidAppear function?

Comment: try `self.searchController.active = false` in `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: @Gokul thanks! It works! good

Comment: yeah man, shall i add this as answer?